# Prevent Azure Data Studio from opening json-like content in new tab

Tags: azure-data-studio

It appears that Azure Data Studio inspects the contents of cells in the query results pane and changes its behavior depending on what it assumes a cell to contain. This is mostly fine, but one specific case keeps bugging me and I can't find any way to toggle it off.

Sometimes when clicking a cell, Azure Data Studio will insist on opening a new tab to show its content. This is very disruptive, especially when the cell was clicked for basic selection purposes (e.g. before copy-pasting its content, or simply to highlight it while screen-sharing during an online meeting), and kind of drives me crazy on a pretty regular basis.

I know for a fact that such behavior exists for cells containing JSON data, so I have tried turning off "Show JSON As Link" in the settings. This effectively changes the way cells containing actual JSON are shown and *sometimes* it seems to be working (a.k.a. no impromptu "navigation" when clicking such a cell). Also, JSON cells used to be shown "as links" (e.g. underlined), are now displayed using the default font style.

However, this keeps popping sometimes, and I can't figure out why or how I can prevent this. As I'm typing this, I have a simple SELECT statement yielding half a dozen rowns from a table, and inside the query results clicking any cell from one specific VARCHAR(1000) column triggers a systematic "open in new tab" behavior, even when the clicked cell contains an empty string. What's more, I couldn't reproduce this when trying to emulate similar queries (e.g. using "FROM (VALUES (...))" clauses) even when copy-pasting data from the offending column.

Any thought or hint regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to somewhat resolve the issue by disabling the setting,

> Convert URL-like text to links in the Markdown preview.

But after clicking around a few times the issue would return until I reran the query. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I noticed that it wouldn't happen on the first row cell I clicked but if I scrolled down, it would start happening and wouldn't stop until I reran the query

Comment: Yeah, I ended up activating this flag too and it seems to help but the issue still creeps up sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a bug : https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/24929

Should be corrected in the next release November 2023 Hotfix 1 : https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/milestone/109